# Modifying HTML tag elements using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to modify HTML tag elements, I have a huge list of HTML files which needs to be modified.

I need the lines between the images and the following text removed. I am using PHP. I am using a DOMDocument to access all the nodes and I am also able to get the nodepath. But I am unable to  get to modify that particular HTML tag from the nodepath. Is this possible?

This is what I have as of now:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($pathname);
$i=0;
$allNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
$tagNamesArray = array();
foreach($allNodes as $node) {
$tagNodePath = $node->getNodePath();
$tagName = end(explode('/',$node->getNodePath()));
$tagNamesArray[$i][1] = $tagName;
$tagNamesArray[$i][2] = $tagNodePath;
$i++;
}

checkForLines($tagNamesArray, $dom);

function checkForLines($tagsArray, $dom) {
$xPath = new DOMXpath($dom);
for($i=0 ; $i<(count($tagsArray)-1) ; $i++) {
    if($tagsArray[$i][1] == 'img' && $tagsArray[$i+1][1] == 'br') {
        echo $tagsArray[$i+1][2].'<br>';
        $lineTag = $xPath->query($tagsArray[$i+1][2]);
        $domElement = $dom->removeChild($lineTag);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML you're attempting to modify? Perhaps the intended resulting HTML as well.

Comment: You could also make it easier by not using the cumbersome raw DOMDocument for modification. phpQuery or QueryPath allow for `qp($html)->find("div a")->wrap("<p class=new>");` for example.

Comment: @JonathanSampson -- consider any image and after it some following text(be it <p> or <h1> etc...) between the image and text there are <br> tags which I want removed. I already have a file iterator which I am able to get the html files but I am unable to modify the source code.

Comment: @Guru: are you ever saving the file back to disk with `$dom->saveHTMLFile($filename)`?

Comment: @Guru Going on your comment here, I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...consider any image and after it some following text(be it `<p>` or `<h1>` etc...) between the image and text there are `<br>` tags which I want removed...

If this is all you want to do:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( "<img src='foo.png' /><br/><p>Hello World</p>" );

$img = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

foreach ( $img as $current ) {
    $sibling = $current->nextSibling;
    if ( $sibling->nodeName === "br" )
        $current->parentNode->removeChild( $sibling );
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Which results in the following output:

```
<img src="foo.png"><p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. My aim is to change a bunch of things but this was the fundamental step which I needed to understand. This works but for some reason, the image is not being displayed and this is not overwriting the original file. Any idea why ?

Comment: @Guru If you want to write over the old file you need to use the [`$dom->saveHTMLFile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php) method. With regards to the image not being displayed, make sure you use *your* HTML, and not the sample HTML I used in the question. Instead of `$dom->loadHTML()`, use `$dom->loadHTMLFile( $filename )`.

Answer (score 0):

Create DOM from string

```
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');

$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';

$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

echo $html;
```