# How can I get HTML elements with PHP?

Tags: php, html, smarty

I am trying to get the `HTML` of my page with `PHP`. I saw that this is possible using `DOM` to go through the elements of your HTML file but I am using `Smarty` to create my HTML so I do not know if it is the reason that I am getting stuck here.

What I want to get of my HTML it is an `<span>` tag inside a `form`. I want the `<span>` tag, not the value of that span (that I suppose that will be retrieved if you get `<span>` tag).

Searching on SO I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655127/modifying-html-tag-elements-using-php) that it is what I have used as reference to make my code.

Here it is my HTML snippet (without headers to simplify it):

```
<div id="content">
    <br>
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action="http://localhost/login" method="post">
        User
        <input type="text" name="user"><span id = "userRegistered" style = "color:red; margin-left: 10px; display: none"> User already registered </span><br>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
 </div>
```

and here what I have tried in PHP:

```
$html = "../template/login.tpl"; //I have the php file in a folder and the template in another folder in the same directory. It is the reason I put ../
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($html);

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("span");

foreach ($items as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
}
```

I am using `var_dump($item)` because I want to see how many spans it gives to me (Of course, after see that it gives to me the correct output I will work with that output). It should gives me one but it does not give me anything.

**I do not want to use Javascript or plugings to get it. I only want to know if it is possible to do this only with PHP.**

### What I want to achieve

Change the `css` property of my `<span>` tag from `display:none` to `display:initial`. What I am trying to do it is to get the `<span>` tag and after change its css but first I need to get that span.

**The reason why I need to change the css using PHP**

I need that this span will be hidden all the time so I put directly `display:none` but I need that, after a condition in PHP that checks if the user already exists or not, if the user it is already registered, this span will be shown. By the moment I am only trying to change the css before doing the condition because first of all I want to see if it is possible or not to get it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to do with the span, after you get it?

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `$html` variable at all... How does it know what file to load?

Comment: @AlexAndrei Modify its css (that I saw that it can also be done with PHP).

Comment: Why are you parsing HTML in PHP which you're creating with PHP to begin with...?! Why not generate different HTML in the first place?

Comment: @toomanyredirects Ok you are right. I prove now with $html but it does not work anyway.

Comment: @deceze What do you mean? It is the first time I use DOM to get HTML file and I do not how it works very well.

Comment: use php or smarty to write the css of the span directly, there's no need to write the span, then get it and then modify it. If you update your question to include exactly what you want to do, including the conditions, we might be able to help more

Comment: Are you getting errors, https://3v4l.org/73SFc, loading it as a string works..

Comment: You should check the return value of [`loadHTMLFile()`](http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php). Maybe the script cannot open the file.

Comment: @AlexAndrei I updated my question. If you need additional info tell me and I will make another update. Thanks!

Comment: Again: why do you need to ***change*** the CSS of the span? Why not write `display: initial` directly into your .tpl file? Or if you need to change it conditionally: use the Smarty templating language which you claim to be using to change it within the template. – Generating HTML using Smarty to then parse it using PHP to then change an attribute to then output the HTML again is quite madness.

Comment: @deceze I want that this span will be hidden all the time. It is why I put it directly to `display: none` but I want that, if a user tries to register with a new user that it is already registered this span will be shown. This is the reason why I need to change it after PHP condition will be done. Here I do not put the condition because first of all I want to try to change the css before continue with the full program to see if it is possible or not.

Comment: Soooo.... **change it in the template using Smarty!?** Do you have some specific reason why you're not doing that?

Comment: @deceze Do you mean to put it directly `display: initial` always? Just because I do not need that it will be shown always. Sorry if I am missunderstanding you.

Comment: Do you understand what Smarty is and what it's for? You should probably be using this: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl

Comment: You are going about this in a very wrong way. Read [this](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl#language.assigned.variables) and then [this](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl).

Comment: @deceze Sorry. I was missunderstanding you before about what you were refearing. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: @Fiskie Thank you very much for point me in the correct way. I put now the answer with the solution I have done. Again, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, thanks to @Fiskie and @deceze for point me in the correct way, I got it out. Here is my code:

On my PHP side:

```
if(some condition here)
{
   $this->$smarty->assign('found', 'initial');
   $this->$smarty->display('login.tpl');
}
else
{
   $this->$smarty->assign('found', 'none');
   $this->$smarty->display('login.tpl');
}
```

On my HTML side:

```
<div id="content">
    <br>
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action="http://localhost/login" method="post">
        User
        <input type="text" name="user">
        <span id = "userRegistered" style = "color:red; margin-left: 10px; display: {$found}"> User already registered </span><br>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Good job - not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but it works. The next step would be to make sure you're not duplicating the entire `<span>` and just modify the value you're interested in; initial or none.

Comment: @Fiskie Answer edited. Again, thank you for point me in the good way :)